# $(xml).find('').each(function() is not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am doing a function when employee apply leave,they have to select **Start_Date** and **End_Date** and below has 1 label will show **How many days who has applied** ,and what i do is when **End_Date** is onchange will call a JavaScript function and use ajax submit, calculation and ajax submit is work fine, but the problem is **I cannot get the number of days and assign to the label**.
This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Start Date <span class="required"> *</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="start_date" name="start_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value=""> 
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date <span class="required"> *</span></label>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="end_date" name="end_date" onchange="getWorkingDays()" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value=""> 
       </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Requested</label>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
       <label for="field-1" class="control-label" id="days"></label>
       </div>
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   function getWorkingDays() {
       var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
       var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
       var data = "action=countLeaveDays&start_date=" + start_date + "&end_date=" + end_date;
       $.ajax({
           url: "apply_leave_application.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: data,
           success: function(xml) {
               alert(xml);
               $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                   alert(123);
                   var label = $(this).text();
                   $("#days").val(label);
               });
           }
       });
   }
```

**When I alert XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
 <head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">                   
  <link href="../asset/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">        
  <link href="../asset/css/guardian.css" rel="stylesheet">                    <!-- Date and Time Picker CSS -->
 <link href="../asset/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />                <!-- All Icon  CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/fonts/entypo/css/entypo.css" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" >   
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><!-- Data Table  CSS -->
 <link href="../asset/css/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />         <link href="../asset/css/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="../asset/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>                <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries --><!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// --><!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></scri..."">
 <a href="employee/dashboard/inbox">Inbox</a></li>                                             
 <li class=""><a  href="employee/dashboard/sent">Sent</a></li></ul></li>                                       
 <li class=""><a href="leave_application.php">Leave Application</a></li>                                     
 <li class=""><a href="all_notice.php">Notice</a></li>
 <li class=""><a href="all_holidays.php">Holidays</a></li></ul>
 <ul class="main-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                     
 <li class="dropdown">
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile<b class="caret"></b></a>                                         
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class=""><a href="employee/dashboard/change_password">Change Password</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li></div><!-- /.navbar-collapse --></nav></div></nav></div></div></header></div>

  <item>2</item>
```

`<item>2</item>`This is only what i want,I have try

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() { 
        alert(123);
            var label = $(this).text();
            $("#days").val(label);
        });
```

its not responding

Comment: $.parseXML should be used when... parsing xml with jQuery. but... that doesn't look like xml at all.

Comment: @KevinB  I have use the same method for my previous project and its work, I am not sure why this time is not working

Comment: what does `console.log($.fn.jquery)` give you in that success callback?

Comment: this is not xml!! But HTML I guess which is not complete, you dont have `body` tag.

Comment: I should how to solve this problem?